# Add elements dynamically to an array in JAVA

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, allocation

This code is making me crazy it's supposed to add elements to a table but it seems that only last element entered exists in the table can someone test the code and fix it up for or send me a method which with I can add elements dynamically to a table, I mean without knowing the number of elements to add.

```
import java.lang.String;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Facture {

private float Remise;
private float THT;
private float tva;
private float quantite;
private static String v1;
private static float v2;
private static int choix;
private static String R="o";

public static void main(String[] args) {  
Scanner stdin=new Scanner(System.in);

System.out.println("1.Ajouter un produit au system");
System.out.println("2.Retirer un produit au system");
System.out.println("3.Nouveau achat");
choix=stdin.nextInt();

int i=0,j=0;
Produit[] t_p=new Produit[i];

if(choix==1)
{   
  do
  {
   t_p =new Produit[i+1];
   System.out.println("entrer le nom du produit");
   v1=stdin.next();
   System.out.println("entrer le prix du produit");
   v2=(float) stdin.nextDouble();
   Produit p=new Produit(v1,v2);
   t_p[i]=p;
   i++;
   System.out.println("Voulez vous ajouter un autre produit o/n:");
   R=stdin.next();
  }while(R.toLowerCase().equals("o"));

  while(j<t_p.length)
    {
        t_p[j].Affiche();
        j++;
    }

}

System.out.println("i: "+i);
System.out.println("length: "+t_p.length );

System.out.println("t_p[0]: "+t_p[0].nom);
System.out.println("t_p[1]: "+t_p[1].nom );
}}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could just use an [ArrayList](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html).

```
List<Produit> array = new ArrayList<Produit>();
Produit p = new Produit();
array.add(p);
```

If you need an array with dinamic size for an exercise or something like that, look at [this implementation.](http://algs4.cs.princeton.edu/13stacks/ResizingArrayStack.java.html)
Basically you need to double the array size when the limit is reached and copy all the elements to the new array.

Comment: thank you very much i haven't used JAVA for a very long time so you can imagine how stupid i became in this language

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you are allocating a new array for every iteration in the 'do' loop:

```
  t_p =new Produit[i+1];
```

then you fill out the last element of it:

```
   t_p[i]=p;
```

But you forgot to copy over all other elements from the old array.

Why using this scheme at all? Can you yous a list instead, i.e. ArrayList?

Comment: done it and it's working fine thank you for your help